# Animating a Sphere and Creating Static Plot Lines

Tags: list-manipulation, regions, animation

I have a data set $\xi(t)$ for some numbers that I generated, and let's just say they're wholly positive numbers for now such that we can make $\xi$ like the following:

```
xi = {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0}
```

and I've learned later that $\xi$ is the radius of a sphere. I want to be able to animate my data set so that I have a sphere of the form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \xi(t)^2$.

However, when I do try to animate it, the closest thing I can get to a functioning animation requires

```
Animate[RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= a^2 , {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, -a, a}], {a, -5, 5}]
```

And I don't know what to do from there either, because the boundaries of the plot do not stay static on the range $a \in [-5, 5]$.

Any and all help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'd do something like `ListAnimate[Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, #] , Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, PlotRange -> 5] & /@ xi]`.

Comment: Ooh, that works nicely. Thank you so much! It's a bit slow, but I'm sure that I can fix that with some editing– less complicated than I expected, for some reason as well. Again, thank you.